# Pac4j Exception handling in JavaEE

Tags: pac4j

We are using pac4j in a javaEE application running on a wildfly server.
We use pac4j with pac4j-buji to get user ids through OIDC and bridge them into the shiro subject.
Our problem is that we throw a custom exception when the user lacks some application specific permission to view something. We show a custom error page if such an exception is thrown by defining the following in the web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>my.app.PermissionDeniedException</exception-type>
    <location>/access.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Without pac4j the `PermissionDeniedException` will be wrapped in a `jakarta.servlet.ServletException` and the correct page `access.xhtml` is shown to the user.
With pac4j the `ServletException` is wrapped again in a `java.lang.RuntimeException` by the `org.pac4j.core.engine.AbstractExceptionAwareLogic#handleException(Exception e, HttpActionAdapter httpActionAdapter, WebContext context)` method. This causes the `web.xml` to **not** recognize it as a `my.app.PermissionDeniedException` and therefore does not show the correct error page.

The documentation illustrates a way to fully implement my own `SecurityFilter` (https://www.pac4j.org/3.7.x/docs/how-to-implement-pac4j-for-a-new-framework.html) which would certanly work but I wanted to ask if there is a simpler way to modify the default exception handling?
I have searched here on stackoverflow and the old google groups for some similar problem but as far as I am aware this question wasnt asked before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the version of pac4j you use, but yes, you should be able to override the `handleException` method in a custom `SecurityLogic`, `CallbackLogic` and `LogoutLogic` and define these new ones at the `Config` level or at the filter level.